# Counting conditional occurrences in an array

Tags: python

I have a 2D array of the form: `np.zeros((m,n))`.
My objective is to look at the first 2 columns, I want to find the element in the first column that is occurring the most (so the mode of the first column), however I do not want to count it twice if the second column is the same.

5x3 example:

```
[[1 2 x], [1 2 y], [1 3 z], [5 3 w], [5 6 v], [9 2 x], [9 2 y],]
```

Desired output, i.e. the number of occurrences of:

```
[1]: 2
[5]: 2
[9]: 1
```

So in a way it is a counter function but conditional on a second array (column 2).

I am relatively new to Python, is there a function that can do this directly and somewhat efficiently? I need to run it on very large matrices, but could not find such a function.

Comment: So you want to search at the first two columns and only count them if they are unique. Off the top of my head: you could try sorting the array by the first column and then check if the 1st and 2nd item are the same as the previous entry, if they are add 1 to counter, if not print the first item and then how many it found.

Comment: the problem is that I will need to sort the first column, and then sort the segments of the second column that correspond to the same value in the first column, and finally I will have to loop iteratively over the second

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I think you can sort the first two columns with one run. You have to treat `[1 2 x]` as a `12` so it goes after `[1 0 z]`. Then you count.

Comment: well if there is no direct function to efficiently do this..then I will have to go about it this way. Thank you!

Comment: In your example you say you want to count 2 ones. Does this mean that the tuple `[1 3 z]` is completely discarded? If you had three more tuples with `[1 3 something]` would you want to return 4 when you count the ones? (since you would have four tuples starting with `[1 3]`). I think what you want is pretty complicated and specific for it to be already implemented as a standard function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This funciotn solves your problem.

```
def count_special(arr):
    counter = {}
    for i in np.unique(arr[:,0]):
        sec = arr[arr[:,0]==i,1]
        counter[i] = len(np.unique(sec))
    return counter
```

which, for your input, returns:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,0],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[5,3,1],[5,6,0]])
print(count_special(arr))
```

-> {1: 2, 5: 2}